# Binding SourceItem for ListView without xaml code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try set `BindingContext` for ListView in code style. I thought this is easy to realize and tried do this like this:

```
        source = new List<string>() { "item 1", "item 2" };
        var MsgsList = new ListView();
        MsgsList.BindingContext = source;
        MsgsList.ItemsSource = MsgsList.BindingContext as List<string>;
```

And I hoped that when then I'll append item to `source` during program execution, `MsgsList` automatically will change the view, but this is not happening.

Most of the examples I've seen on the Internet use xaml for this. There is some the easiest way to attach a permanent `List<string>` binding to the ListView using just code style (`*.cs`) without xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [SetBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings) to programatically create a binding

```
MsgsList.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, ".");
```